# CSS Transition to specific location

Tags: javascript, css

I found an example, credit given to: http://jsfiddle.net/g9dn1a09/ and I am trying to modify it so that the CSS element transitions when clicked to given coordinates and then repeats.

The issue I am having is that my code is transitioning the element to different than needed coordinates.

How can I make this happen?

Thank you

JavaScript

```
var $box = $('.box'),
    $btn = $('.toggle');


$box.on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('right')) {
        $this.removeClass('right').addClass('down');
    } 
    else if ($this.hasClass('down')) {
        $this.removeClass('down').addClass('left');
    }
    else if ($this.hasClass('left')) {
        $this.removeClass('left').addClass('up');
    }
    else if ($this.hasClass('up')) {
        $this.removeClass('up').addClass('right');
    }

    else {
        $this.addClass('right');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: transform 1s;
}


.right {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform: translateX(100px);

}
.down {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform: translatey(100px);

}
.left {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform: translatex(100px);

}
.up {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform: translatey(0px);

}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: You should edit this question to make it clear what your code is doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cumulate the translation and not define a new one each time because you will simply reconsider the initial state and you won't have any continuity in your mouvement:

```js
var $box = $('.box'),
  $btn = $('.toggle');


$box.on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('right')) {
    $this.removeClass('right').addClass('down');
  } else if ($this.hasClass('down')) {
    $this.removeClass('down').addClass('left');
  } else if ($this.hasClass('left')) {
    $this.removeClass('left').addClass('up');
  } else if ($this.hasClass('up')) {
    $this.removeClass('up').addClass('right');
  } else {
    $this.addClass('right');
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(100px) translateY(0);
}

.down {
  transform: translateX(100px) translateY(100px);
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(100px);
}

.up {
  transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```